# Swift - Closures in function arguments

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to iOS and swift, trying to understand the basics. I tried the below two function calls in playground and I was expecting the result to be same but the first one returned one value and the second one returned two values.

Would you be able to explain me why?

```
func sqrt(a: Float) -> Float {
    return a * a
}

func avgOfSqrts(a: Float, b: Float, f: (Float -> Float)) -> Float {
    return (f(a) + f(b))/2
}

avgOfSqrts(2,3,sqrt) //returns 6.5

avgOfSqrts(2, 3, {x in return x * x}) //returns 4.0 and 9.0
```

shouldn't the function call with closure return 6.5 as well?

Thanks!

Comment: returns returns 4.0 and 3.0 or returns 4.0 and 9.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But the results are the same. You can try assign it to a var

```
var result = avgOfSqrts(2, 3, {x in return x * x})
result //this is 6.5 as expected
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought playground will display the result, rather it looks like it shows each execution. after assigning it to a variable, the result looks the same.